# nativescript Gridlayout - define columns and rows using numbers

Tags: nativescript

I have unknown number of rows (i'm calculationg this by getting length of Http response ad dividing by two.)
So if my array has 100 entries, the number of rows will be 50 as i'm using 2 columns grid layout.
My question is simple: Is possible to bind this number somehow ? Or i have to convert this as 50 (*) stars?
So instead of doing this :

rows= * ,* ,* ,* ,* ,* ,* etc...
i would like to use binded value for example:

```
<GridLayout rows="{{ length+'*' }}" columns="*,*" class="calendar" />
```

But this will not work.
Is there a way to do this smart?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and here is working [POC](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=KYzvEJ). But it could be a overkill for your app. Why don't you try [RadListView with GridLayout](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/item-layouts#using-listviewgridlayout) instead, it could be the optimised solution for display bulk data.

Comment: Hi @Manoj, thanks for this.
I've tried nativescript-grid-view plugin, but for some reason i had issues with images rendering from the API - they was not loading at start, you had to scroll down/up and them images appeared, and also it was pain to set static heights...
I didnt know this Radlist and i will def check now. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `GridLayout` programmatically and use `addRow()`. Check out the article [Demystifying NativeScript Layouts](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/demystifying-nativescript-layouts).

Note that you don't have to build the whole `GridLayout` programmatically. You can create the `GridLayout`, then grab a reference to it and call `addRow()` to add rows.

Answer (score 0):

The rows and columns have to use strings. Not numbers.
Angular syntax: [rows]="".
JS syntax: rows={{}}

In .ts file define property:

```
rowsVar = '*, auto';
```

In .html file use:

```
<GridLayout [rows]="rowsVar"></GridLayout>
```

**Or**

In .ts file define property:

```
rowsVar = '100';
```

In .html file use:

```
<GridLayout [rows]="'*,auto,'+rowsVar"></GridLayout>
```